# markdown module has no inlinepatterns attribute

Tags: python, markdown

I'm writing a markdown extension, but when I run it from the python command line:

```
>>> import markdown
>>> markdown.markdown('foo --deleted-- bar', ['myextension'])
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inlinepatterns'
```

On this line:

```
md.inlinepatterns.add('del', del_tag, '>not_strong')
```

I've updated markdown to 2.3.1 and I'm running it in Python 2.6. The interpreter appears to be finding my mdx_myextension.py file as the tracebook reflects that it has registered the extension.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are referencing the attribute by the wrong name.
Use `inlinePatterns` instead of `inlinepatterns`.

See [Python Markdown documentaion - extensions api](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/api.html#extendmarkdown)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to import `markdown.inlinepatterns`

#### Markdown extension code

```
import markdown
import markdown.inlinepatterns

DEL_RE = r'(--)(.*?)--'

class MyExtension(markdown.Extension):
    def extendMarkdown(self, md, md_globals):
        # Create the del pattern
        del_tag = markdown.inlinepatterns.SimpleTagPattern(DEL_RE, 'del')
        # Insert del pattern into markdown parser
        md.inlinePatterns.add('del', del_tag, '>not_strong')

def makeExtension(configs=None):
    return MyExtension(configs=configs)
```

#### Example code

```
import markdown
import mdx_myextension

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print markdown.markdown('foo --deleted-- bar', ['myextension'])
```

Reference: http://achinghead.com/python-markdown-adding-insert-delete.html